# Delete a white space using css

Tags: css

How can I eliminate the white space between the normal price and the digital price in my single product page? Take a look to this screenshot:[image: screenshot]

Here the URL: https://www.editorialufv.es/catalogo/territory-inhabited/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may add this to your custom CSS in order to remove margin bottom of price and reduce this white space :

```
p.price {
   margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: And how is it possible to delete the white space only when there's also the digital price, but not in other cases. For instance, in this case I'd like to have the white space between the price and the short description of the product: https://www.editorialufv.es/catalogo/universitarios-socialmente-responsables/

Comment: @Stefano you can for example increase the margin of short description like this `.woocommerce-product-details__short-description {
    margin-top: 20px;
}`

Comment: Easy and great solution. Thx